# How to customise ag-grid icons?

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid, glyphicons

I am trying to achieve few customisations in ag-grid such as:

1. Change icons of Grid Header - Sort Icon, Filter Menu Icon, Icons of different menu items in Filter Menu, etc.
2. Change position of the Icons.

Can anyone point me to a possible solution?

Comment: custom icons are easy and in the docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Thanks Jarod. I was looking more specifically to change the position of the icons. If you have any idea - it will be useful.

Comment: Did you find a way to change the position of filter icon.?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-icons/#gsc.tab=0), you can try this CSS after the loading of the `ag-grid.css` (or scss) file and the `ag-theme-<themename>.css` file. In my example, that theme file is for Balham theme `ag-theme-balham.css`. This CSS will change the icons from default black (using the SVG) to white.

```js
/*
 * The override should be placed after the import of the theme.
 * Alternatively, you can aso increase the selector's specificity.
 */
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-desc,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-asc,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-menu
{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    /* FontAwesome uses font-weight bold */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-desc::before
{
    content: '\f063';
    color: white;
}

.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-asc::before
{
    content: '\f062';
    color: white;
}

.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-menu::before
{
    content: '\f0c9';
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me. Just overide the color

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-menu:before,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-asc:before,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-desc:before,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-icon-filter:before{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```